# d3 line update with empty dataset

Tags: d3.js, dataset

I am creating a line with the d3 line generator and feed it with a dataset; this dataset is updated every hour.

```
var myline = d3.svg.line()    
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

svg.append("path")
  .data(dataset)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", myline(dataset));
```

However, every full hour the dataset is reset and is empty. Feeding the line with an empty dataset however leaves it unchanged, while I would expect it to be deleted since it has no data.

Is there a way to delete the line when it is fed with an empty dataset?

Comment: you can either delete the line and then run the function again to create the line. So just select by id and remove. Or you can just give it default values, for example, all zero's. An example may benefit. Also, by empty do you mean no data at all ? How do you represent an empty data set?

Comment: the dataset comes empty like dataset=[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to help you without seeing your data and how you are updating the chart, but it seems to me the issue here is that you are repeatedly appending a path element based on a data array (which you don't even need to bind with the data function) every time you update the chart.

An alternative is appending the path only once and changing its `d` attribute every time you update the chart. That way, if the data is empty, the path won't show up.

Here is a demo, every five seconds the data array is empty:

```js
var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  data.push({x: i*3, y:Math.random()*150});
}

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .x(d=>d.x)
  .y(d=>d.y);

var line = svg.append("path")
  .attr("fill","none")
  .attr("stroke","black");

var t = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  var newData = data.slice(0,(t%100)+1);
  line.attr("d", lineGen(newData));
  t++;
}, 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: This is an exactly what I am looking for. Hopefully I will manage to replicate this in my own code. With an empty dataset I mean dataset=[]. If the dataset contains values even null, it works as it should, however I am creating a line out of what an API sends, and am receiving dataset=[] from time to time

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment, I just updated my answer. In the demo, the empty dataset is `[]`, just as in your case.

Comment: ...looks like my mistake was binding the updated dataset on the line before updating it. :/